# momentjs format returning date a day off?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using momentjs to format my dates. However it is displaying the date a day off and I'm not sure why. Here is the code I'm using:

`moment(date).format('MMMM do YYYY, h:mma')`

where `date = Sat May 05 2018 00:26:53 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

However the result is `May 6th 2018, 12:26am` - showing may 6 instead of may 5.
Does anyone know why this may be? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code where date is set?  Or output the date as miliseconds since epoch, to confirm that it is the output that is off, and not the input?

Comment: Sounds like a matter of ambiguous standard... 

11:59pm is like saying 23:59. By adding 5 minutes, you'll get 12:04am (also known as 00:04am) which is like saying 24:04 (also known as 00:04)
I don't know if it was clear :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing non-ISO string without specifying the format, which will result in a warning on the console, and may show the wrong date.

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

Always pass the format as a preventive measure. Coming to your problem, to display the date correctly, you need to use `Do` specifier, instead of `do`. The former is for **Day of Month** but latter is for **Day of Week**.

```js
var date = moment('Sat May 05 2018 00:26:53 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)', 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss');
console.log(date.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mma'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I haven't received any warnings in the console though.. But replacing the `do` with `Do` was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @picklechips -- then maybe you are using an old version of MomentJS. Try your code on the MomentJS' site, and you'll know.